# How do I count the number of submitted GET params?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have a view method that I want to serve the page with an empty form if no GET params were submited and otherwise build the form and validate it.

```
def get(request):
    if no GET params submitted:
        tax_calculator_form = TaxCalculatorForm()
        ...
    else:
        form = TaxCalculatorForm(request.GET)
```

How do I figure out how many (if any) GET parameters were submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.GET` is basically a dictionary. In Python, dictionaries - like lists and other containers - are boolean False if they are empty. So you can just do:

```
if not request.GET:
```